# Can I use a while or for loop to print the list?

Tags: c++, circular-list

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

namespace  forward_circular_linked_list {
    typedef struct Node {
        std::string data;
        Node *nextNode;
    }Node;

    class ForwardCircularLinkedList {
    private:
        Node *head;

    public:
        ForwardCircularLinkedList() : head(nullptr) {}

        void AddItem(std::string data) {
            Node * newNode = new Node();
            newNode->data = data;

            if(head == nullptr)
            {
                head = newNode;
                newNode->nextNode = head;
            } else{
                Node * copyOfHead = head;
                while(copyOfHead->nextNode != head)
                {
                    copyOfHead = copyOfHead->nextNode;
                }
                copyOfHead->nextNode = newNode;// process last node
                newNode->nextNode = head;
            }
        }
        void print()
        {
            Node * copyOfHead = head;

            do
            {
                std::cout<<copyOfHead->data;
                copyOfHead = copyOfHead->nextNode;
            }while(copyOfHead != head);
        }

    public:
        static void Test() {
            ForwardCircularLinkedList list;
            list.AddItem("Hello");
            list.AddItem(" ");
            list.AddItem("World");
            list.AddItem("!");
            list.print();
        }
    };
}
```

here, a **do-while** is being used to print the elements of the list.

At the current setup, Can I use a **while** or **for** loop to print the list?

**Note:** I am considering `do-while` and `while` as different looping structures.

Comment: Your current print will actually fail if the list is empty, fyi.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah, this is a circular buffer, it should stop after winding once.

Comment: @alfC Sorry - I misread the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `do-while` or a `for` loop.
But `do-while` is more natural because it checks the condition *after* the body of code.

You have a circular data structure and (presumably) you want to print each element once.
Doing only one round of circling.
`do{...move circulator}while(compare with head)` has the right logic.

CGAL implements "circulators" and does exactly that, it starts from "head" does something and increments the circulator until it is head once again.
See https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Circulator/classCirculator.html (scroll to Example).

Note the example also checks for *emptyness* at start, but probably you want.
(In my mind a circular buffer is never empty, but I accept other opinions.)

---

With `while` you have:

```
        Node * copyOfHead = head;

        do
        {
            std::cout<<copyOfHead->data;
            copyOfHead = copyOfHead->nextNode;
        }while(copyOfHead != head);
```

With `for` you can have

```
        Node * copyOfHead = head;

        for(;;){
            std::cout<<copyOfHead->data;
            copyOfHead = copyOfHead->nextNode;
            if(copyOfHead == head) break;
        }
```

or

```
        for(Node * copyOfHead = head;;){
            std::cout<<copyOfHead->data;
            copyOfHead = copyOfHead->nextNode;
            if(copyOfHead == head) break;
        }
```

or

```
        for(Node * copyOfHead = head; ; copyOfHead = copyOfHead->nextNode){
            std::cout<<copyOfHead->data;
            if(copyOfHead->nextNode == head) break;
        }
```

or (exploiting that the body of the loop evaluates to bool:true)

```
        for(
            Node * copyOfHead = head;
            std::cout<<copyOfHead->data;
            copyOfHead = copyOfHead->nextNode
        ) if(copyOfHead->nextNode == head) break;
```

The main advantage of `for` is the initialization, but still it is not worth it.
You can of course do the step outside the loop but then you have repeated code, etc.

(NOT RECOMMENDED, it may even have a bug)

```
        Node * copyOfHead = head;
        std::cout<<copyOfHead->data;
        copyOfHead = copyOfHead->nextNode;

        for(; copyOfHead != head ;copyOfHead = copyOfHead->nextNode){
            std::cout<<copyOfHead->data;
        }
```

**So, there you have, `do-while` is exactly what you want for this kind of data structure! and `for` (or `while-only`) is exactly what you *don't* want.**

Comment: Can u kindly show me how to use while loop by keeping other parts of code unchanged?

Comment: I was considering `do-while` and `while` as different looping structures. On the other hand, you are considering them as the same. Hence the confusion.

Comment: Sorry, if it was confusing I was always talking about `do-while`, `while-only` for this problems have the same drawbacks as `for`.